# Is it possible to highlight detected text using the Google Cloud Vision Nuget in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

is it possible to highlight detected words or paragraphs from the text detection option while using the Google Cloud Vision NuGet in Xamarin when developing an Android App? This is the NuGet's [link.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/) [This image shows the effect I want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVFL0.png) Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from the API you won't receive the words highlighted; however, in the [response](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageResponse#EntityAnnotation) you can get the bounding boxes of the detected text. You can then use another library to manipulate the image and modify it with the information obtained.